# Filtering data.table rows by the presence of a column in a strsplit of another column

Tags: r, data.table, strsplit

I have a data table:

```
dt <- data.table(col1=c('aa,bb', 'bb,cc,ee', 'dd,ee'), col2=c('aa', 'cc', 'aa'))
> dt
    col1      col2
1: aa,bb      aa
2: bb,cc,ee   cc
3: dd,ee      aa
```

I want to check if column 2 occurs in the strsplit of column one, so for the first row if `aa` is present in `aa,bb` split by a comma, which is true. It's also true for the second row, and false for the third. I only want to keep the rows where this occurs, so only row 1 and 2.

My first thought was doing it like this:

```
dt[col2 %in% strsplit(col1, ',')]
```

However, that returns an empty data.table.

I can think of multiple solutions to solve this, including making new columns using `tstrsplit`, or melting the data table, but all of these are a bit tedious for such a seemingly simple task. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `str_detect` from `stringr`

```
library(stringr)
dt[, flag := str_detect(col1, col2)]
dt
#       col1 col2  flag
#1:    aa,bb   aa  TRUE
#2: bb,cc,ee   cc  TRUE
#3:    dd,ee   aa FALSE
```

Also, to avoid any substring matches, we can specify the word boundary (`\\b`)

```
dt[, str_detect(col1, str_c("\\b", col2, "\\b"))]
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

---

Regarding the use of `strsplit`, the output would be a `list` of `vector`s.  So, we need to use a function that checks the values of 'col1' are in the corresponding elements of `list`.  `Map` does that

```
dt[,  unlist(Map(`%in%`, col2, strsplit(col1, ",")))]
```

To apply the filter in the same step and return the 2 row data.table:

```
dt[unlist(Map(`%in%`, col2, strsplit(col1, ",")))]
```

Comment: Regarding your first solution, I was also thinking along those lines, but if row1 would be `baap,bb`, it would evaluate to true whilst it is not true.  Second solution works fine though, so thanks :)!

Comment: @Joost To avoid that you can use the word boundary, i.e. `dt[, str_detect(col1, str_c("\\b", col2, "\\b"))]`